# Save folder connection in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arccatalog

In ArcCatalog one has the option to save locations of folders via the "Connect To Folder" button. I have the problem, that ArcGIS don`t save each folder connection which I would like to have in Catalog.

Everytime I fail when I want to save the path **U:\GROUPS\GIS\Geo_Data** or **U:\GROUPS\GIS**. Whereas **U:\GROUPS** or **C:\home\data** is no problem.

Anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Do you receive any error message? Is that your local path or network?

Comment: No, nothing. I can "click" through my folder structure until I reach my folder and click "OK". One path is then available in ArcCatalog, the other unfortunately not and nothing happens.

Comment: Are you saying that you are able to browse to a folder location using the Connect to Folder dialog but when you hit OK no new connection appears? I don't think you should need to refresh the Catalog tree in this instance but perhaps try hitting F5.

Comment: No success - unfortunately.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can add the path but you can't save/bookmark it?

Comment: One quirk I had with 10.0 (10.1 seems to have fixed it) was that I had to manually type in the connection in the Location window in order for ArcCatalog to remember it. If I used Connect To Folder, it didn't work.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try this at ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 or 10.2?  If so, does the problem persist?